# Vu gen script pass but not performing few steps in application

Tags: loadrunner

When I am executing my script in Abu gen it passed but when I do check on application few steps are not executing

Please give me solution

Answer (score 0):

Each step has an expected result.   Check the content for the correct expected result and branch your execution if you do not have the correct result.

HTTP 200 is no guarantee of a PASS.  Your application could be throwing application errors with a correct HTTP 200 status for a well formed page.

This answer assumes a web virtual user.